# Check Constraint Violated Error, But Column Unspecified

Tags: sql, oracle

I've made the following table below:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
Employee_ID      NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Company_ID       NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL REFERENCES 
Penrhyn_Jet_Charter(Company_ID),
First_Name       VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
Last_Name        VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
Address          VARCHAR2(300) NOT NULL,

Email_Address    VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (Email_Address                  
LIKE '%_@__%.__%'),
Telephone_Number NUMBER(15)    NOT NULL CHECK (Telephone_Number > 0),
Mobile_Number    NUMBER(15)    NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (Mobile_Number>0), 
Date_Of_Birth    DATE          NOT NULL,
Gender           CHAR(1)       NOT NULL, CHECK (Gender = 'M' OR Gender 
= 'F'),

NI_Number        VARCHAR2(10)  NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (NI_Number Like 
'[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z]'),
Job_Description  VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
Annual_Salary    NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL CHECK (Annual_Salary > 0)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Check_Date_Of_Birth
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF( :NEW.Date_Of_Birth < DATE '1900-01-01' OR 
:NEW.Date_Of_Birth > SYSDATE )
THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20001, 
'Date of birth must be later than Jan 1, 1900 and earlier than today' 
);
END IF; 
END;
```

The above table was created with no errors.

But when I'm trying to populate the table, It's gives me this error:

> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (1, 1, 'Gary', 'Turner', '5 Orpington Street, Crawley, CR18 25J',
>   'garyturner@mail.com', 087948743, 938468364, TO_DATE('1985-05-06','YYYY-MM-DD'),
>   'F', 'aa111111a', 'Pilot', 12500)
>   Error report -
>   ORA-02290: check constraint (K1651915.SYS_C0074079) violated

This is my insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (1, 1, 'Gary', 'Turner', '5 Orpington 
Street, Crawley, CR18 25J',
'garyturner@mail.com', 087948743, 938468364, TO_DATE('1985-05-
06','YYYY-
MM-DD'),
'F', 'aa111111a', 'Pilot', 12500);
```

It doesn't specify which column's check constraint it violates, so I'm confused.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: is the primary key for the employee table is Auto Increment?

Comment: No it isn't, I think the error might be originating from NI-Number. But why do you ask about the PK for Employee being Auto Increment?

Comment: TO_DATE('1985-05-06','YYYY-MM-DD') are u sure this not causing any error in query INSERT INTO?

Comment: The error message contains name of the of the violated constraint (SYS_C0074079). You can select hat from user_constraints that will get you he table and column.

Comment: No it isn't I just double checked with a fake table, I've narrowed the problem down to the NI NUMBER check constraint....

Comment: Yeah, the problem is with the NI_Number format validation CHECK Constraint, I have no idea how to sort that.

Comment: Yea sorry that should have said :                                                               select * from USER_CONS_COLUMNS where constraint_name = 'SYS_C0074079';  not user_constraints.

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions. The only wildcards that `LIKE` supports are `%` and `_`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52142

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, your CHECK CONSTRAINT uses a REGEXP check, but is actually expecting a WHERE check.

If you want to use regular expressions inside your check constraint, you'll need to use REGEXP_LIKE:

```
CONSTRAINT ck_ni_number
  CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(ni_number, '[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z]'))
```

This code would go at the end of your CREATE TABLE statement. I've declared it this way (caleld and out-of-line constraint) as it allows you to name the constraint and easily see the error will relate to ni_number.

Your entire CREATE TABLE statement would then look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
Employee_ID      NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Company_ID       NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL REFERENCES Penrhyn_Jet_Charter(Company_ID),
First_Name       VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
Last_Name        VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
Address          VARCHAR2(300) NOT NULL,
Email_Address    VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Telephone_Number NUMBER(15)    NOT NULL,
Mobile_Number    NUMBER(15)    NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Date_Of_Birth    DATE          NOT NULL,
Gender           CHAR(1)       NOT NULL, 
NI_Number        VARCHAR2(10)  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Job_Description  VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
Annual_Salary    NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ck_ni_number 
  CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(ni_number, '[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z]')),
CONSTRAINT ck_tel_num CHECK (Telephone_Number > 0),
CONSTRAINT ck_email CHECK (Email_Address LIKE '%_@__%.__%'),
CONSTRAINT ck_mob_num CHECK (Mobile_Number > 0),
CONSTRAINT ck_gender CHECK (Gender = 'M' OR Gender = 'F'),
CONSTRAINT ck_an_salary CHECK (Annual_Salary > 0)
);
```

Also, I would suggest specifying the columns in your INSERT statement. Without the column names specified, Oracle will assume an order of your values, which is not guaranteed.

To do this:

```
INSERT INTO Employee
  (employee_id, company_id, first_name, last_name, address, 
  email_address, telephone_number, mobile_number, date_of_birth, 
  gender, ni_number, job_description, annual_salary)
VALUES (1, 1, 'Gary', 'Turner', 
  '5 Orpington Street, Crawley, CR18 25J',
  'garyturner@mail.com', 087948743, 938468364, 
  TO_DATE('1985-05-06','YYYY-MM-DD'),
  'F', 'aa111111a', 'Pilot', 12500);
```

One other suggestion I would make is that you may want to consider making the phone_number and mobile_number fields VARCHAR2 instead of numeric. This is because phone numbers may start with 0, and phone numbers don't have any arithmetic performed on them. But that's outside the scope of your question!

Hope that resolves your issue.